# Angular Firebase - How to add a property to document in firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a problem with angular firebase solution.

What I'm trying to do is to add a property to already existing in firestore document.

I have the user interface that looks like this

```
export interface User {
    email: string;
    uid: string;
    photoURL?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    teams?: string[];
}
```

I want to create a team and add that team id to `teams` array in the existing User object.

I don't want to get all user data, but just put a new value to that field.

Is that possible? Maybe you have some suggestions on how to do that more efficient?

The team interface looks like that

```
export interface Team {
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    admin?: string; // = creator - first user
    members?: string[]; // array of users UIDs.
    boards?: string[]; // array of board docs id.
}
```

The component responsible for adding a team is just a form so `onSubmit()' I've tried doing the following but I have no idea how to put that team document id to the user object.

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const newTeam: Team = {
        name: form.value.name,
        description: form.value.description,
        admin: this.auth.currentUserId,
        members: [this.auth.currentUserId],
    };
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(
        `users/${this.auth.currentUserId}`
    );
    let teamRefId = '';
    this.afs.collection('teams').add(newTeam).then((docRef) => teamRefId = docRef.id);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dash');
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe that should be some kind of spread operator but once again I don't want to get user object and post it back to firestore but just update that one field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by updating the doc with the following:

```
let teamArray = []; // if not excisting.
teamArray.push(teamRefId); // or just add it if it's.
userRef.update({teams: teamArray});
```

An update will not change the anything else except the team. If the team not excist the team will be added.

Comment: ok but i want the user to have more than one team. So will it add a value to teams array or just update single one?

Comment: Then you have to get all teams of this user first add the team to the already excisting array. Check out my edit.

Comment: If you want to query an array can use `array-contains`.